# Rails 5.0 - How to dynamically render a nested form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have `expenses` which have multiple `expense_types`, and each `expense_type` has a form with multiple, specific fields.

Upon creating an `expense`, I can select which `expense_type` it will have, and through **AJAX** I'd like to `render` the `fields_for` the selected `expense_type`.

For example, let's say an `expense` has a person's `name` and `expense_cost`: upon selecting the `expense_type` `travel`, it also includes the fields `itinerary` and `start_date`/`end_date` on the page.

I have the following lines of code to render any of the selected `expense_types`, within the `expense` form:

```
<% if @expense_type.present? %>
  <%= f.fields_for ("expense_#{@expense_type}").to_sym do |ff| %>
    <%= render "expense_#{@expense_type.pluralize}/#{@expense_type}_form", f: ff %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I call an action to set `@expense_type = params[:selected_expense_type]`, and then tell it to render `:new`, it'll display the selected form as intended, but I'll lose the data the user had already supplied.

How can I set this variable without losing the `expense`'s current form data? Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to send the current form's content through AJAX and set the `expense` object with it, then I added this to my `ApplicationHelper`:

```
def render_if_exists(path, *args)
  render path, *args
rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
  nil
end
```

and updated my renderer with it:

```
<% if @expense_type.present? %>
  <%= f.fields_for ("expense_#{@expense_type}").to_sym do |ff| %>
    <%= render_if_exists "expense_#{@expense_type.pluralize}/#{@expense_type}_form", f: ff %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With this, I'm able to load the `expense`'s form alone, then upon selecting an `expense_type` from the dropdown, it would send a request back to `expenses/new` with the current form's content and set the `@expense` object with the old values, as well as looking for a partial which would match my convention (`expense_expense_types/expense_type_form`), and rendering it if it found one for it.